# Android uses-configuration VS uses-feature

Tags: android, android-manifest

What is the difference between uses-feature and uses-configuration tab? And yes i already read everything from this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) and this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-configuration-element.html). Still confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Configurations" refer to those device characteristics that might cause an application to need different resources.

"Features" refers to other device characteristics, where the app typically would not need different resources.

So, for example, an app might use different layouts for a non-touchscreen device (e.g., Google TV) versus a touchscreen device. An app is unlikely to need to change layouts, or any other type of resource, depending on whether or not it has GPS.

In the case of both `<uses-feature>` and `<uses-configuration>`, the app is telling the device and the Market what its expectations are. Apps are filtered out of the Market for devices for which it is incompatible, as indicated by these two elements (or other elements, like `<uses-sdk>`).